# Mobiwire Aquila

Tags: android

Hello guys(and girls:),

I got a problem. I bought [this phone](http://mobiwire.com/portfolio/aquila/), and to tell you the truth its not bad phone for this price range. Now the problem is I do the android developement on linux and if you want to test your application on your phone you need to write udev rule for it. Now I wrote udev rules before  and is not rocket science. The problem is that MobiWire is not listed on google android developers [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

I've tryed google'd the thing but with no luck, so if theres anyone who knows how to address this issue I would be greatly thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem. Its not that complicated.

First to find out your usb ID of your device use to command:

```
lsusb
```

This will give you interesting output and the line you are looking for is this one:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0bb4:0c03 High Tech Computer Corp.
```

Or something similar to this one. I did one lsusb command before I hoked the device to the computer and one after, and then I just diff-ed those outputs to get the line I needed.
Here you will get device ID in the output. For MobiWire Aquila device ID is the same as HTC devices as you can see above, ID="0bb4". Now we can start writing the udev rule for this device.

Open as super user this file: "/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"
and if you want to support all the predefined ID's copy [this file](https://gist.github.com/3890058) into it. Now you need to restart the udev daemon. If you are on ubuntu do this:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

or you can use udevadm to reload the rules like this:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Ok, almost done here. Now you need to check if this work. We gonna check it with adb tool which you get with android-sdk, actually you get it now when you update the platform-tools in android-sdk. Download the android-sdk [from here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). When you download it, unpack it and enter the folder. Hit this command:

```
tools/android update sdk --no-ui
```

This will download the platform-tools and one of those tools is adb(android debug bridge) which is client-server program for handling connected device. Now here is really important to start this adb server in super user mode, otherwise you will get permission error on the device. To do so, enter the "android-sdk/platform-tools" and hit:

```
sudo ./adb start-server
```

This will start the adb server. Now go to your device, go to settings->applications->developemnt and enable the USB debuging mode and connect your device with the computer. Once you did that, hit this command in your terminal:

```
./adb devices
```

And hopefully you should see something like this as your output.

```
(1:2008)$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF    device
```

This is it, happy development. :)